# form with select parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

**MrYoshiji and me solve it, please see our comments above of his answer**

I added a part of my `_form.html.erb` code.

I want three things please:

1) the @admin_mail will be the admin_mail that the user is asked to fill (I don't want to show the option of "admin_mail", but the admin_mail will be: @admin_mail)

2) there are options in order to choose the user_mail. I want that the choice will be inserted to the user_mail.

3) 'done' will be automatically by false (and don't show it).

```
<div class="field">
    <%= @admin_mail %>
    <%= f.label :admin_mail %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :admin_mail %>
</div>

<div class="field">
   <select>
     <% @workers.group_by(&:email).each do |email, tasks| %>
        <option value="<%= email %>"><%= email %></option>
     <% end %>
   </select>
   <%= f.label :worker_mail %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :worker_mail %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :task %><br />
  <%= f.text_area :task %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :done %><br />
  <%= f.check_box :done %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

I think that in order to set the check_box of done by default (false), I have to define:

```
t.boolean :done, :default => false
```

and remove the next lines from the form:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :done %><br />
  <%= f.check_box :done %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 2):

You can use [`f.select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select) to generate the select box and options:

```
f.select :worker_mail, @workers.map{ |c| [c.email, c.email] }
```

instead of this part of code:

```
<select>
  <% @workers.group_by(&:email).each do |email, tasks| %>
    <option value="<%= email %>"><%= email %></option>
  <% end %>
</select>
```

## 3):

**set the attribute "done" to false on creation**:
You can use a `[after_create][2]` callback ([link to the callbacks doc in general](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)). It is a callback to use like this:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  after_create :set_done_to_false

  def set_done_to_false
    self.update_attributes(done: false)
  end
end
```

Then you don't need to display the part of the form concerning the done attribute.

## 1):

Instead of your code:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= @admin_mail %>
    <%= f.label :admin_mail %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :admin_mail %>
</div>
```

Use a hidden_field with a value = @admin_email:

```
 f.hidden_field :admin_mail, :value => @admin_mail
```

Comment: thank you very much!
about the question number 1, I have a parameter of email. I want that the user will not asked to fill this field. I want this field will be @admin_mail (that I got from the controller).

Comment: thank you.
about 1, I didn't explain clear, but I don't want to show the field of: admin_mail. in your solution for that, the admin_mail was inserted to this field, that it's ok because I want that admin_mail will be this field, but I don't want let the user an option to change it.

Comment: about 2, I got errors :/ undefined method `merge' for #<Array:0xb5ec3ed8>
Extracted source (around line #20):

17: </div>
18:   <div class="field">
19:    
20:      <%= f.select('task', 'worker_mail', @workers.map{ |worker| [worker.email, worker.email] }) %>
21: 
22:     <%= f.label :worker_mail %><br />
23:     <%= f.text_field :worker_mail %>

Comment: I updated my answer (points 2 & 1): hidden_field_tag and options_for_select is what you need ;)

Comment: thank you again, 2 doesn't work :/ I got the same errors of my last comment. I am updating my question, in order to show what I wrote in my code. thanks!

Comment: MrYoshiji, question 1 was fixed. I should do: <%= f.hidden_field :admin_mail, :value => @admin_mail %> please update your answer to question number 1 (I don't succeed question number 2) :/ thank you!

Comment: this is the answer for the second question:

<%= f.select :worker_mail, @workers.map{ |c| [c.email, c.email] } %>

Comment: Updated, Are all you problems fixed?

Comment: yes. in the 3 question, I did: <%= f.hidden_field :done, :value => false %>